# ignore null objects of eager loaded data- laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, orm, eager-loading

I have folowing JSON returned by ORM

```
[
{
"id": 3,
"name": "Card Department",
"name_burmese": "Card Department",
"is_active": "1",
"created_at": "2014-11-23 07:02:07",
"updated_at": "2014-11-23 07:02:07",
"orm_bank_contact": []
},
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Loan Department",
"name_burmese": "Loan Department",
"is_active": "1",
"created_at": "2014-11-23 07:01:16",
"updated_at": "2015-02-24 09:05:35",
"orm_bank_contact": []
},
{
"id": 4,
"name": "Remittance Department",
"name_burmese": "Remittance Department",
"is_active": "0",
"created_at": "2015-02-24 09:43:25",
"updated_at": "2015-04-17 12:26:07",
"orm_bank_contact": []
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Deposit Department",
"name_burmese": "Deposit Department",
"is_active": "1",
"created_at": "2014-11-23 07:01:34",
"updated_at": "2015-04-20 14:04:27",
"orm_bank_contact": [
{
"id": 27,
"bank_department": 2,
"mobile": "9843139168",
"phone": "9843139168",
"email": "shresthabeenu@gmail.com",
"contact_person": "Binu Shrestha",
"address": "No. 416, Mahabandoola Road, Kyauktada Township, Yangon, Myanmar",
"is_active": "1",
"created_at": "2015-04-15 08:50:16",
"updated_at": "2015-04-15 08:50:16",
"bank_id": 13
}
]
}
]
```

but i just need

```
[

{
"id": 2,
"name": "Deposit Department",
"name_burmese": "Deposit Department",
"is_active": "1",
"created_at": "2014-11-23 07:01:34",
"updated_at": "2015-04-20 14:04:27",
"orm_bank_contact": [
{
"id": 27,
"bank_department": 2,
"mobile": "9843139168",
"phone": "9843139168",
"email": "shresthabeenu@gmail.com",
"contact_person": "Binu Shrestha",
"address": "No. 416, Mahabandoola Road, Kyauktada Township, Yangon, Myanmar",
"is_active": "1",
"created_at": "2015-04-15 08:50:16",
"updated_at": "2015-04-15 08:50:16",
"bank_id": 13
}
]
}
]
```

I need to fetch record with child on eager loaded objects

I tried below

```
$bank_contact = BankDepartment::with(array('OrmBankContact' => function($query) use($bank_id){
            $query->where('bank_id', "=", $bank_id)->where('bank_department','>',0);}))

            ->get();
```

But no luck.. what is the proper way?

Answer (score 3):

This query should do the job returning only departments with OrmBankContact

```php
BankDepartment::has('OrmBankContact')->get();
```

[See Eloquent docs on querying relations](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations)

Answer (score 0):

1. Model BankDepartment

   ```
   class BankDepartment extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public function OrmBankContact(){
       return $this->hasMany('OrmBankContact','bank_department','id');
    }
   ```

   }
2. Model OrmBankContact

   ```
   class OrmBankContact extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

       public function BankDepartment(){

       return $this->belongsTo('BankDepartment','bank_department','id');
     }

   }
   ```

In Any controller you can get like this

```
$OrmBankContact = BankDepartment::with('OrmBankContact')->get();
$OrmBankContact = $OrmBankContact->toArray();
echo '<pre>'; print_r($OrmBankContact); exit;
```